# Absolute positioning in relation to a input[type=range]

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm missing something simple here.

I am trying to build a custom range input and I need a tooltip to appear over the input - the tooltip needs to follow the range input as it moves.

Normally, I'd just use :after and position the tooltip that way, but I need HTML in this tooltip so I need to resort to JS.

However, I can't seem to figure out the calculations for ensuring the tooltip is positioned on the exact left edge for the input range thumb.

I put together a [codepen](http://codepen.io/chrisronline/pen/vNPdoN) showing the issue

I have two borders - one on the absolutely positioned tooltip and one on a :after property (for comparison). The :after property border stays on that left edge perfectly but the tooltip doesn't - the math seems pretty simple and basic so I must be misunderstanding how this works.

HTML

```
<div class="tooltip">
  <p>How can I get this border to <em>consistently</em> align with the one on the thumb?</p>
</div>
<input type="range" min="0" max="9"/>
```

CSS

```
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border-left: dotted 2px orange;
  padding: 2px;
  max-width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=range] {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #000;
  border-left: dotted 2px orange;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}
```

JS

```
$('input[type=range]').on('change input', function() {
  var max = 9;
  var value = $(this).val();
  var percent = value / max;
  var width = $(this).width();

  var left = percent * width;

  $('.tooltip').css('left', left);
}).val(4).trigger('change');
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the OP correctly, i guess all you need to do is this:

**Updated:**

```
var left = percent * width + 10 - value;
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/evbxewfL/1/)

---

**Edit:**

As mentioned in a comment by Brandon,the `10` in the above formula represents the `body` padding, if the body `padding:0` then that wouldn't be accurate, use this after reseting body padding:

```
var left = percent * width - value;
```

or this:

```
var left = percent * width + 1 - value;
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/evbxewfL/2/) and [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKOmbE).

Comment: That makes it look fine when it is centered, but the math isn't quite right when you place the range slider to the right or left. I believe the ratio is off a bit, maybe the value needs rounded down or up to a certain degree..

Comment: This doesn't work - it might align the dotted borders on _some_ values, but not all - like Brandon said, it must be a ratio thing but I don't understand what it needs to be

Comment: @ChrisRoberson, check it out now

Comment: @Brandon, Correct! it is the body padding thing, but i am testing on JSFiddle and if i reset body padding and change it to `var left = percent * width - value;` it looks behind by `1px`, it was fixed with this `var left = percent * width + 1 - value;` after padding reset, same result on codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKOmbE

Comment: I still don't think works - If I look at the pen when the slider is on the far left, it appears like the tooltip border is slightly more left than the :after border. But if I move the slider to the far right, the tooltip border is slightly more right than the :after border. Are you seeing this too?

Answer (score 1):

Mi-Creativity is correct that you need to subtract the **value** from the **left** calculation. However, you also need to account for the padding/margin of all parent elements to the input.

If you give the input an id of "input1", the calculation should be this:

```
var left = percent * width + $('#input1').offset().left - value;
```

Comment: I had figured out the offset().left part, but you figured out the value part. Teamwork

Comment: Right, however is the final answer since my answer wouldn't work if the slider or its container is shifted horizontally and not at zero offset left value

Comment: This isn't working for me either - the farther right I move the slider, the more the tooltip border moves over the thumb.

Comment: [Here's a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbPmVd) of the working code. I tested it in IE and Chrome and it seems to be working. If it still isn't working as intended, could you elaborate on the issue?

Comment: Sure - [here is an imgur album](http://imgur.com/a/axJts) of what I'm seeing. It's not lining up for me

Comment: That's using [the codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbPmVd) I posted in my above comment? Which browser are you using?

Comment: Yea using that codepen. Chrome Version 46.0.2490.86 (64-bit) on OSX 10.10.5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95580/discussion-between-chris-roberson-and-brandon).